# Using VB.NET, what is the correct way to match two text files by a keyword?

Tags: vb.net

My question is how do I do the looping to compare two text files in VB.Net.  The value, if exists, from one file will be used to update the value in the second file.

File1:

```
SSN1    AA
SSN2    BB
SSN3    CC
SSN4
SSN5    DD
```

File2:

```
SSN1   ZZ
SSN3 
SSN5   YY
```

Output:

```
SSN1    ZZ
SSN2    BB  - not updated because not on file2
SSN3    CC  - not updated because of blank on file2 
SSN4        - not updated because not on file2 
SSN5    YY
```

Comment: Do the values in File2 *always* appear in the same order as they do in File1? Could *new* lines be added from File2, or are they only updates?

Comment: both are same order, file2 can have values file1 does not have..  Thank you!!!

Comment: I notice that the first column appears to be in some sort of order. What happens if you get to SSN10? Does it sort alphabetically, so SSN1, SSN10, SSN2,..., or does it need the numeric part compared as numbers, so SSN9, SSN10, SSN11,...? Does it always start with "SSN" and have only "SSN" followed by digits (that is, no SSN1a etc.)?